# onActivityResult(...) не вызывается

Tags: android

Здравствуйте!

У меня в контроллере при нажатии на кнопку вызывается метод `selectImage()`. Он работает как надо, но метод `onActivityResult(...)` не вызывается.

Как правильно в контроллере получить изображения из галереи?

```
public class EditProfileController extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private int LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS = 1;
    private static Activity activity;
    private static Context mContext;
    private static ViewHolder v;

    /**
     * EditProfileController This can be called at the start first time
     * @param activity Activity will transferred from onCreate in EditProfile.class
     */
    public EditProfileController(Activity activity) {
        this((Context) activity);
        this.activity = activity;
        v = new ViewHolder();
    }

    /**
     * EditProfileController This can be called when there is not activity available.
     * @param context Context will transferred from onCreate in EditProfile.class
     */
    public EditProfileController(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void onCreate() {

        // set the view to activity
        activity.setContentView(R.layout.edit_profile_layout);

        // call to initView
        // @param activity
        initView(activity);
    }

    /**
     * initView called from onCreate and get the view from xml
     * @param view View that called from constractor
     */
    public void initView(Activity view){

        // Get the  view
        v.imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image_edit_profile);
        v.username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
        v.country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.country_select);
        v.uploadImg =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.upload_image);
        v.save = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_save);

        // call to method
        setListenner();

    }

    /**
     * setListenner called from initView and set click listenner
     * @param
     */
    public void setListenner(){

        // set click listenner
        v.imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        v.uploadImg.setOnClickListener(this);
        v.country.setOnClickListener(this);
        v.save.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    /**
     * onClick
     * @param view View that called that onClickEvent
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_save:
                EditProfileConstractor editProfileconst = new EditProfileConstractor(v.username.getText().toString(),v.username.getText().toString(),v.country.getText().toString());
                break;
            case R.id.upload_image:
                selectImage();
                break;
            case R.id.country_select:
                pupupCountryDialog();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * ViewHolder
     * @param
     */
    private static class ViewHolder {
        // the view holder
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView username;
        private TextView country;
        private TextView uploadImg;
        private Button save;
        private String imagePath;

    }


    /**
     * pupupCountryDialog popup dialog with countries
     * @param
     */
    private void pupupCountryDialog() {
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(mContext)
                .title(R.string.app_select_country)
                .items(R.array.countries_array)
                .itemsCallback(new MaterialDialog.ListCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                        v.country.setText(text);
                    }
                })
                .negativeText(R.string.app_cancel)
                .show();
    }

    /**
     * selectImage start gallery image intent
     * @param
     */
    private void selectImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

             // Let's read picked image data - its URI
        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
        // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
        String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

        // Now we need to set the GUI ImageView data with data read from the picked file.
        v.imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));



        // At the end remember to close the cursor or you will end with the RuntimeException!
        cursor.close();

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: А метод `onActivityResult(...)` находится в каком классе? И `activity` – это экземпляр какого класса? Покажите весь код.

Comment: пожалуйста если сможете подскажите что надо изменить чтобы контроллер был максимально правильным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При запуске активити вот таким образом:

```
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);
```

результат придет в ту самую `activity`, а не туда, откуда Вы ее вызываете.

Вообще говоря, у Вас какая-то не очень понятная *мешанина* в коде.

Коль уж Вы наследуетесь от `AppCompatActivity`, то попробуйте заменить эту строчку:

```
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);
```

на вот эту:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);
```

Ну и это, в моем понимании термина *контроллер*, он не должен наследоваться от класса активити.

Comment: не магу получаю NullPointerException

Comment: @DavidKern, На какой строчке?

Comment: startActivityForResult(intent, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);

Comment: @DavidKern, Могу лишь посоветовать Вам как минимум разделить контроллер и активити на два отдельных класса.

Comment: да вы правы наследовать не надо но если не наследовать   то super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  в красном цвете

Comment: @DavidKern, вызывать super вам вообще не надо. Попробуйте его удалить просто

Comment: @DavidKern, Результат нужно получать не в контроллере, а в активити.

Comment: да вы правы получил в активити

Comment: а как мне переправить в контроллер изображение ?

Comment: @DavidKern, Добавьте в контроллер метод, который будет получать изображение и совершать над ним необходимые манипуляции, а потом из активити вызывайте этот метод.

Comment: огромное спасибо вам post_zeew ,ЮрийСПб :))))))))))